# Replace slash and quotes

Tags: c#, string, replace

How to replace inside of strings?

```
    first string is = "1.jpg"
    with
    second string is \"cid:image1\"
```

Well, I didn't put it in string cause having trouble with that, you can name it `string1` and `string2` and replace it with `string3`.

UPDATE

put in `string1` value `"1.jpg"`, and in `string2` `\"cid:image1"`, and replace `string1` with `string2` to get in `string1` value `\"cid:image1"`

The problem is how to replace `\` if you can't write it?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want...

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.. Please clerify your question..

Comment: I still can't figure out what you mean, even after your edit ^^

Comment: That didn't make it any more clear. Do you want to extract the `1` from the first string, and put it into the end of the second string?

Comment: Your edit made your question even more unclear...

Comment: Head exploding with latest update...

Comment: @Belogix - I know the feeling :D

Answer (score 5):

```
var string1 = @"""1.jpg""";
var string2 = @"\""cid:image1\""";
string1 = string2;
```

Comment: A cynical answer to a terrible question.

Comment: I am pretty sure this does exactly what was asked. +1

Comment: it's not cynical i can't put inside of string those values ... just put in string1 value "1.jpg", and in string2 \"cid:image1", and replace string1 with string2 ... thnx

Comment: @john - Are you not making sense on purpose, or are you actually trying to tell us something here? Why would you replace all of `string1` with `string2`? Then you can write `string1 = string2`

Comment: in the textfile i have to replace \"cid:image1\" with "1.jpg"

Comment: @spender thnx for answare it is what i need it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Replace` method

LInk : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/fk49wtc1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

According to update, I'll give it a shot:

```
var string1 = @"""1.jpg""";
var string2 = @"\""cid:image1""";
string1 = string2;
```

- put in string1 value "1.jpg" CHECK!
- and in string2 \"cid:image1" CHECK!
- and replace string1 with string2 to get in string1 value \"cid:image1" CHECK!

According to specification! But it still gives no sense why you want to put something specific in `string1` when you want to overwrite the entire thing afterwards anyway.

Comment: I think we've arrived!

Comment: string2 is \"cid:image1" exactly you don't have \ at begining and on the end "

Comment: I'm voting to close now. This is way stupid.

Comment: @john - Sorry. Fixed it now ;)

Comment: @spender, I'm with you, this is out of control.

Comment: thnx for answare it is what i need it yvind knoblock-brathen

Comment: @john - If this is what you needed, there are greater issues with your application than this question I'm afraid.